# web-gRPC Performance Rate per second

Tags: benchmarking, grpc, rate, grpc-python

I want to develop a system for trace and debugging an external device via COM port.
Main service will be developed using python to receive, analyse & store logs data. 
We decided to stream log data to web browser with gRPC protocol and draw live charts.
Highest rate if data is 50K of signals per second and maximum size of every signal is just 10 bytes.
System will be used in local network or same PC so we do not have bandwidth limits.
We want to make sure the web-grpc platform can cover this rate per second.
Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

The throughput limit is mostly decided by the browser and the protobuf overhead. Since the latter is application specific, you should do a benchmark with real data on your preferred browsers.